# WP_Query does not work within plugin WP_AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am making a plugin, and using ajax inside of it.

I put this code in main.php, but got fatal error at the line of WP_Query.

```
function my_ajax() {
  header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
      $the_query->the_post();
      echo $the_query->post->ID;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
  die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax', 'my_ajax' );
```

WP_Query is not able to work in wp_ajax?
May be, wp_query is not loaded before wp_ajax.
So, is there any way load the WP_Query class by myself or some?
and if you know the power way like a Chuck Norris KARATE kick, I do not care, just want to get a resolve.

regard.

Comment: I solved by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Cause was PHP Memory over. I did 2000 posts AJAX sending in my test.
I put this in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

I could see log in /wp-contents/debug.log, that said Memory over.

So I change $arg　parameters for narrowing-down, WP_Query working.

regard.